# Get results of people that are in A but not B and vise versa [SQL Server]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to get a list of people that have only col1 subscription or only have col2 subscription, from table1. Table2 is used for referencing. I have the query that finds each separately, but how would I put the output in one?

Note: Table2 has many more columns, but for the sake of simplicity I haven't added them in here. I need to get all the details from table2.

```
--This will get people that have col1 and not col2
select *
from table2 
inner join table1 on col1 = table2.col1
where table2.col1 not in (select col2 from table1)

--This will get people that have col2 and not col1
select *
from table2 
inner join table1 on col1 = table2.col1
where table2.col1 in (select col2 from table1)
```

So how would I join the results of these 2 queries into one? Without union. Because I need the output table to have col1 and col2 and if one is present the other should be null.

```
|                  Table1                |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Col1           |     Col2         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          A          |         F        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          B          |         G        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          C          |         H        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          D          |         I        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          E          |         J        |
|---------------------|------------------|



|        Table2       |
|---------------------|
|      Col1           |
|---------------------|
|          A          |   
|---------------------|
|          B          |
|---------------------|
|          C          |         
|---------------------|
|          D          |
|---------------------|
|          E          |
|---------------------|
|          F          |   
|---------------------|
|          G          |
|---------------------|
|          H          |         
|---------------------|
|          I          |
|---------------------|
|          J          |
|---------------------|
```

Comment: how about left join?

Comment: what do you mean by _I need the output table to have col1 and col2 and if one is present the other should be null_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join to table 2 twice and then check that one and only one subscription column in table 1 matches:

```
SELECT
    t1.Col1,
    t1.Col2
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 a
    ON t1.Col1 = a.Col1
LEFT JOIN table2 b
    ON t1.Col2 = b.Col1
WHERE
    (a.Col1 IS NOT NULL AND b.Col1 IS NULL) OR
    (a.Col1 IS NULL AND b.Col1 IS NOT NULL)
```

## Demo